# Sql Server - Constraint - Allow to set column A only if column B is null and vice-versa

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

Is there a way to add a constraint in SQL Server 2008 that will verify that if a user try to enter a value in a column A, it can only if column B is null and vice-versa

Example

- if A is NULL, B can have a value
- if B iS NULL, A can have a value
- A and B can't have value at the same time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo WITH CHECK ADD
    CONSTRAINT CK_Foo_reason CHECK (
        ColA IS NOT NULL AND ColB IS NULL
        OR
        ColA IS NULL AND ColB IS NOT NULL
        )
```

Edit: after question update

<strike>It depends if both columns are allowed NULL in which case</strike>

```
        ColA IS NULL OR ColB IS NULL
```

Edit 2: For 3 columns, exactly one of which must be NOT NULL

No smarty-pants answer I'm afraid. I've added spaces to hopefully make it clearer

```
ALTER TABLE foo WITH CHECK ADD
    CONSTRAINT CK_Foo_reason CHECK (
        ColA IS NOT NULL AND ColB IS NULL     AND ColC IS NULL
        OR
        ColA IS NULL     AND ColB IS NOT NULL AND ColC IS NULL
        OR
        ColA IS NULL     AND ColB IS NULL     AND ColC IS NOT NULL
        )
```

Comment: Reading his question it seemed to me that he only wants one to be NOT NULL at a time

Comment: @Tom H: true. This is my 2nd case which matches yours which allows both NULL.

Comment: If I got 3 values, let say a Column C, what will be the constraint condition ?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Constraint
(
    a INT NULL,
    b VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Test_Constraint_CHK CHECK (a IS NULL OR b IS NULL)
)
```

Comment: Good call on my answer Tom. I forgot all about that.